# Hermite Polynomial question

Tags: hermite-polynomials

"If $f(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $m$, show that $f(x)$ may be written in the form $$f(x)=\Sigma_{r=0}^{m}c_rH_r(x),$$
where 
$$c_r=\frac{1}{2^rr!\sqrt {\pi} }\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^2}f(x)H_r(x)dx.$$
Deduce that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^2}f(x)H_r(x)dx=0$ if $f(x)$ is a polynomial of degree less than $n$."

I'm not sure how to get started with this.

Comment: Do you know that the Hermite polynomials are a system of orthogonal polynomials with weight $e^{-x^2}$ on $(-\infty,\infty)$?

Comment: Yes, in fact applying the orthogonality condition was my first idea. But I don't think $f(x)$ is necessarily a Hermite polynomial.

Answer (score 1):

Let $P_m$ be the vector space of polynomials with degree at most $m$. Then $\dim{P_m}=m+1$, since $\{1,x,\dotsc,x^m\}$ is a basis. Since each $H_k$ is a polynomial of degree $m$, $\{H_0,H_1,\dotsc,H_m\}$ must also be a basis (they are linearly independent and spanning by induction: there's no way to make $x^k$ without having a polynomial of degree at least $k$. The first result follows from this.

The second result comes from orthogonality: since $H_m$ is orthogonal to $\{H_0,H_1,\dotsc,H_{m-1}\}$, it is orthogonal to the span of these, $P_{m-1}$.